# How to resolve pods failing due to exceeding pull rate limit from docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-image

**kubectl get all -n migration:**

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx2-7b8667968c-zxtq7   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          5m38s

NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx2   0/1     1            0           5m38s

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx2-7b8667968c   1         1         0       5m38s
```

**kubectl describe pod nginx2-7b8667968c-zxtq7 -n migration:**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       44s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned migration/nginx2-7b8667968c-zxtq7 to k8s-master01
  Normal   SandboxChanged  33s                kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling         18s (x2 over 43s)  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed          14s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
  Warning  Failed          14s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff         3s (x4 over 32s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed          3s (x4 over 32s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

**Post-logging in with different docker account:**

I can manually pull an image from docker using `docker pull nginx`

But while deploying a deployment, it again shows the same error.

**Deployment yaml is as:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  namespace: migration
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: nginx2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: game-demo
            mountPath: /usr/src/app/config
          - name: secret-basic-auth
            mountPath: /usr/src/app/secret
          - name: site-data2
            mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: game-demo
        configMap:
          name: game-demo
      - name: secret-basic-auth
        secret:
          secretName: secret-basic-auth
      - name: site-data2
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: demo-pvc-claim2
```

Also, as the nginx image is present locally, I tried with modifying `imagePullPolicy` to `Never` as well as 'IfNotPresent'.

But nothing works. Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your errror:

```
 Warning  Failed          14s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

Basically docker hub is now becoming a paid thing if you exceed their rate limits.
You can use the publically hosted image of "nginx" from Amazon's ECR instead:

```
docker pull public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest
```

That should be the same as the one you use using, just double check over here:
https://gallery.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx

Comment: As I mentioned, I actually have the nginx image locally and running the deployment with `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Well whether you have it locally or not, that error is showing that Kubernetes is trying to download the image off docker hub.

Comment: If you just wanna resolve your issue then try point it to the nginx image on ECR.
Or even better point it to your nginx image that you have locally, but currently Kubernetes is trying to pull it off docker hub and that is why you are experiencing this issue.